# Excel merged cell contains multiple values problem

Tags: excel

I have encountered an excel spreadsheet, where some merged cells are. The problem is that when i sum over the cells, the value is higher then i can visually see in the cells.

For example: let's say i have merged cells A1:B1 into one and wrote a formula in that cell that gives the result 5 which i can visually see in the cell, but when i sum over the cell, the value is 6. Also upon unmerging the cell i can see formula in cell A1 and number 1 in cell B1.

Obviously, i can sum only over the A column but why is this happening? Has anyone encountered such a thing? I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce what you are describing. Are you able to manually do this in an empty workbook? I mean, put the values, merge and find the sum to be the sum of the multiple cells that consist of the merged cell?

Comment: Documentation states that shouldn't happen (only the upper left cell contents should be retained) when you merge cells.  But I, too, have once seen other cells within a merge retain values. Couldn't figure out why. Merged cells cause problems.

Comment: Merged cells are a nightmare, can you show the actuall '=SUM()` formula that is used. If you trying to use `SUM` on a range of merged cells it will automatically recognize it should also include column B.

Comment: @Jerry No i cannot reproduce it on purpose. It happened in a workbook i am using for a while now and i believe it wasn't like this before...

Comment: @JvdV Yes, as i mentioned i can force the sum to be only SUM(A1:A10) for example, i just can't figure out where the B values came from as i have never put any values into column B. It seems like they've just popped up from nowhere after i merged the cells.

Answer (score 0):

4 years too late I'm sure but I too ran into this problem yesterday while trying to graph something in excel. I had a series of data that used a merged cells and in those cells the data displayed as the correct value however once graphed it displayed wildly different values and when I look in the select data pop up for the graph the series in question showed it was using twice as many "categories" (x axis points) as the rest of the series. In those categories I noticed old data that had existed before I merged the cells and changed the values. The fix I found was to unmerge all the cells. When I did it started displaying the old data that was no longer being displayed and I thought I had deleted. I deleted the values and made the series look right however I have yet to figure out why excel is trying graph the series as if the cells were not merged. Im still getting twice as many data points (categories) as I should.